# Normal Distribution in Bounded Domain with Zero Endpoints

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

Is there a known probability distribution $p(x)$ that approximates a normal distribution near $x=0$, but is bounded within a domain $x \in [a,b]$ such that $0 \in [a,b]$ and $p(a)=p'(a)=p(b)=p'(b)=0$?

Comment: What is $p'(a)$?

Comment: Scaled Beta distributions with both parameters exceeding $1$ have all these properties.

Comment: @Henry $p'(a)$ is the derivative of $p$ at $a$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One nice approximation satisfying those conditions has the pdf

$$p(x)=6\left(\frac{x^2}{25}-\frac14\right)^{\!2} \text{ on }\left[-\frac{5}{2},\frac{5}{2}\right]$$

with $p(x)=0$ outside that range. This is shown below in orange, and is a transformed version of the Beta(3,3) distribution.

[image]

Comment: A Beta distribution (with location and scale adjustment) seems a natural option, and the parameters can be adjusted to aim to reflect other information like a desired density at $0$ or a particular mean and variance

Comment: @Henry This *is* such a Beta distribution.

Comment: @whuber Yes - hence my comment to this answer (+1) rather than to the question

Answer (score 4):

Another potential option is a scaled and translated logit-normal distribution with pdf

$$p(x)=\frac{(b - a)\exp \left(-\frac{\left(\log \left(\frac{x-a}{b-x}\right)-\mu \right)^2}{2 \sigma ^2}\right)}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma  (x-a) (b-x)}$$

with parameters $-\infty<\mu<\infty$ and $\sigma>0$.

Here's an example:

[image: PDF of normal and logit-normal]